# pthread_mutex_t {aka union <anonymous>}’ has no member named ‘abi’

Tags: locking, nim-lang

I've been trying to write a pool of database connections based on a lockable queue (well, seq in this case) called `POOL`. I want to have `POOL` as a global variable and then use `initConnectionPool` to instantiate it. I've tried to do so with the code below

```
var POOL: ConnectionPool

proc initConnectionPool*(initialPoolSize: static int) = 
  POOL = ConnectionPool(connections: @[])
  initLock(POOL.lock)
```

However, this throws a compiler error:

```
‘pthread_mutex_t {aka union <anonymous>}’ has no member named ‘abi’
```

I am not quite sure what this is supposed to mean or what to do about this. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I am fortunately unable to reproduce this with nim v1.6.2 on macOS.

Comment: @hola good point. The above came from nim v1.6.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (git hash as per nim -v: 9084d9bc02bcd983b81a4c76a05f27b9ce2707dd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: As of nim v. 1.6.6 this appears to no longer be an issue and work flawlessly.

For pre nim v.1.6.6:

This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/14873). Thankfully xflywind helped me out an pointed me to the right answer.

`POOL = ConnectionPool(connections: @[])` within the proc is not allowed and causes the compile issue here. What you should be doing here is, instead of instantiating this object, to just assign the individual fields here as if the object already existed, since, in a way, it already does.

So this will compile:

```
proc initConnectionPool*(initialPoolSize: static int) = 
  POOL.connections: @[]
  initLock(POOL.lock)
```